# Using file contents as command line arguments in BASH

Tags: bash, redirect

I'd like to know how to use the contents of a file as command line arguments, but am struggling with syntax.

Say I've got the following:

```
# cat > arglist
src/file1 dst/file1
src/file2 dst/file2
src/file3 dst/file3
```

How can I use the contents of each line in the `arglist` file as arguments to say, a `cp` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the '-n' option for xargs specifies how many arguments to use per command :

```
$ xargs -n2 < arglist echo cp

cp src/file1 dst/file1
cp src/file2 dst/file2
cp src/file3 dst/file3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/read) (this does assume that any spaces in the filenames in `arglist` are escaped):

```
while read src dst; do cp "$src" "$dst"; done < argslist
```

If the arguments in the file are in the right order and filenames with spaces are quoted, then this will also work:

```
while read args; do cp $args; done < argslist
```

Comment: a while read loop will "miss" reading the last line if there is no last newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe (|) :

```
cat file | echo
```

or input redirection (<)

```
cat < file
```

or [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs)

```
xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs
```

Then you may use awk to get arguments:

```
cat file | awk '{ print $1; }'
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: All of these do _something_ but all of them are off target.

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from `stdin`. Besides `cat` doesn't need `echo`. Also, you don't have to redirect into `cat` - this works: `cat file`.

Comment: Yes I know, at the very beginning I didn't understand well what he wanted. I tought the output was like "ls", I mean on cols to take less  lines. This is why I spoke about shell redirections. (english is not my first language, sorry :))

Answer (score 0):

if your purpose is just to cp those files in thelist

```
$ awk '{cmd="cp "$0;system(cmd)}' file
```

Comment: no different when you do it with shell. shell is calling system command too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop with `IFS`(Internal Field Separator) set to `new line`

```
OldIFS=$IFS # Save IFS
$IFS=$'\n' # Set IFS to new line
for EachLine in `cat arglist"`; do
Command="cp $Each"
`$Command`;
done
IFS=$OldIFS
```

Comment: It's not necessary to put the command and its arguments into a variable. Anyway, you'd have to do `$Command` or `\`$Command\`` to make it work.