# Using DOS file contents as command line arguments in BASH

Tags: bash, scripting

This is a follow-up to this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674020/using-file-contents-as-command-line-arguements-in-bash/1674090#1674090).

How can I modify the code so that the annoying CRLF of a DOS created file can be stripped away before being passed to xargs?

Example file 'arglist.dos'.

```
# cat > arglist.unix
src/file1 dst/file1
src/file2 dst/file2
src/file3 dst/file3
^c
# sed 's/$/\r/' arglist.unix > arglist.dos
```

The unix variant of the file works with this:

```
$ xargs -n2 < arglist.unix echo cp
cp src/file1 dst/file1
cp src/file2 dst/file2
cp src/file3 dst/file3
```

For my own education, how can I change it to accept either the 'arglist.unix' or 'arglist.dos' files on the same command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat arglist.dos | tr -d "\r" | xargs -n2 echo cp
```

gives you the same result as

```
cat arglist.unix | tr -d "\r" | xargs -n2 echo cp
```

so it works on both files.

`tr -d "\r"` removes all the CR characters

Comment: Thanks.  I guess what I was after was an understanding of the `<` operator in the original command line; you're example makes it clear to me that `xargs` is taking it's input from `stdin` in both yours an my versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use d2u to remove the CR before passing the file to xargs.

Comment: Different name; same functionality.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it on the same command line, does `d2u`/`dos2unix` support that?

Comment: As with many unix commands, when invoked without parameters, dos2unix operates on stdin and stdout.