# Trying to apply a clearcase command to all files in a list of filenames in a text file

Tags: cleartool

I need to re-label a list of specific files.  I have those filenames (with full paths) in a text file.  How do I pipe the contents of the text file into a cleartool command?
I found the following online but didn't work, as the ls command lists the files in the local directory, not the files in "fileList.txt":

> cleartool ls < fileList.txt
>
> Any help will be appreciated.
>   (my platform is windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if one of the methods mentioned in "[Using file contents as command line arguments in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674020/using-file-contents-as-command-line-arguements-in-bash)".

```
xargs -n1 < fileList.txt echo mklabel -replace MyNewLabel
```

For that, use a bash like one provided with [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases):
Unzip anywhere you want [`PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe), and call:

```
C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\git-bash.exe
```

In it, you will have access to `xargs`.